# Why is this code not sufficiently generic or even better why is that even checked?

Tags: f#

I get an error on the definition of `ToBar`

```
type Foo = {foo: string}
type Bar = {bar: string}

[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractType< ^T> (fn: ^T -> Foo) =

    member inline this.ToFoo (x: ^T) = fn x
    abstract ToBar: string -> Bar
```

This is the error message

```
This code is not sufficiently generic. 
The type variable  ^T could not be generalized 
because it would escape its scope.
```

Apart from the fact that (even after reading all other SO questions on this) I don't get what this error tries to tell me ... but it is totally stunning that `ToBar` which does not even use that type parameter is getting an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `ToBar` is not `inline`, which is a requisite for using statically resolved type constraints. But it seems that you don't really need them, simple generics would be enough. So just replace `^T` with `'T`, and it will work fine:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type AbstractType<'T> (fn: 'T -> Foo) =

    member inline this.ToFoo (x: 'T) = fn x
    abstract ToBar: string -> Bar
```

If you think about it a bit more, it only makes sense: an `abstract` member can't really make use of SRTC, because it's dispatched at runtime, and SRTC-types need to be known at compile time.

On a related note, even if you get rid of `ToBar` in an effort to keep SRTC, you'll hit the next error:

```
error FS1113: The value 'ToFoo' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible
```

This can be fixed by making the type itself private:

```
type private AbstractType< ^T> (fn: ^T -> Foo) =
    member inline this.ToFoo (x: ^T) = fn x
```

This will work, because the type won't be accessible from outside assemblies, and therefore won't need to expose its SRTC parameters.